# Why does this program give "stack smashing error"?

Tags: c

input .txt contents

```
start_point(0)
end_point(100)
turtle_speed(3)
hare_speed(6)
hare_sleep_time(5)
hare_turtle_dist(20)
process_delay(1)
```

stack smashing error occurs if i put hare-TURTLE_DIST GREATER THAN 10

code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void get(int *a,FILE *fp,int i,int j){
    char str[19];
    int input=0;
    fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
    while(str[i]!=')'){
        input=input*10+str[i]-48;
        i++;
    }
    a[j]=input;
    printf("%d\n",input);
}

main(){
    int a[7];
    FILE *fp;   
    int i,j=0;
    fp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    i=12;

    get(a,fp,i,j);
    j++;
    i=10;
    get(a,fp,i,j);
    j++;
    i=13;
    get(a,fp,i,j);
    j++;
    i=11;
    get(a,fp,i,j);
    i=16;
    get(a,fp,i,j);
    j++;
    i=17;
    get(a,fp,i,j);
    j++;
    i=14;
    get(a,fp,i,j);
}
```

Comment: SO is not a "fix my program" site. Isolate the problem, write a short test case that demonstrates the problem, then ask a question. A specific error message, the compiler you are using would also enhance your question greatly. What's a "stack smashing error"? -1. You should also take a good read of the editing-help, so your question doesn't look like the dog's dinner. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I'm beginning to detect a pattern... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442314/write-function-in-hare-fun-is-giving-arbitrary-value-but-it-was-supposed-to-retur, also why so many accounts? http://stackoverflow.com/users/414209/user414209

Comment: @James homework assignment, maybe?

Comment: @Nathon I guess so, explains why everyone is concerned about tortoises and hares and not linked-lists

Answer (score 2):

In function get you have

```
char str[19];
```

which means you are assuming that every string read into it will have at max `18` char. But your input file has the line:

```
hare_turtle_dist(20)
```

which is of `20` char. This leads to crash.

To solve this increase the size of the char array to at least `21`.